# what does "archive" do in makefile

Tags: makefile, archive

in some makefile, I saw the following line:

```
#---- build rule
all: archive
```

what does this mean? any pointer for reference?

Comment: It is defined in the makefile. Search for a target `archive:` ...

Answer (score 1):

Line starting from `#` symbol is just a comment, maybe somewhat fancy =). Second line declares dependency of target `all` from target `archive`, so when you call `make all` from your command line, `archive` target is executed before `all` target.

Answer (score 0):

The general structure for build on make is

```
target_name: dependent_target list
    <Tab> rule for the target
```

When we do `make target_name`, It checks if all its dependency targets are upto date, If not then execute them and finally, it executes your `rules` for the `target_name`

So for your example, `make all` will first execute target by the name `archive`, if required, before executing rules for `all`.